Flashing eMMC Compute Module 4 using Pi 4
So I've been trying to flash the eMMC of my CM 4 using another Raspberry Pi 4. I've used the steps outlined at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/compute-module.html#steps-to-flash-the-emmc
Here's what I did:
Connect jumper cable on J2 to disable eMMC boot on the CM 4.
Connect J11 USB slave to Pi 4
Power Pi 4
Power CM 4
Here's a picture of my setup:


is that all? you physically connected it, and magic didn't happen?

shouldn't i at least see the CM 4 appear as a device on Pi 4 ? am I missing something ? they're both running raspbian

have you run rpiboot?

Yes I did this... Rpiboot stuck on Waiting for BCM2835/6/7/2711

electronics and plastic bags do not play well together ... read this https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/what-is-esd-and-how-to-prevent-it
